# How to speed up installation Homebrew when one is behind the Great Firewall of China?

Tags: networking, mac, vpn, terminal

I live in China, with [Great Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall), not America.

Because of this, when installing Homebrew, it is very slow, and easy to fail.

Because of this, we use network proxy to visit sites outside of China.

This specific step is painful

```
tapping brew/core
```

Is there any way I can speed up the installation of Homebrew in a situation like this?

Because it's fast when using Chrome to watch videos on YouTube?

I can check the network proxy ports (HTTP / SOCKS).

Comment: refer https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/90508170

Answer (score 1):

Information [referenced from here](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/90508170).

If hanging at:

```
tapping brew/core
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, to cancel it, then run these commands:

```
cd "$(brew --repo)/Library/Taps/"
mkdir homebrew && cd homebrew
git clone git://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/homebrew-core.git
```

If hanging at: `cask`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, to cancel it, then:

```
cd "$(brew --repo)/Library/Taps/"
cd homebrew
git clone https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/homebrew-cask.git
```

Comment: +1 Good self solved answer! But instead of using `$(brew --repo)` you can also just directly reference the directory that command outputs: `/usr/local/Homebrew/`. Just look at the output when you run `$(brew --repo)`; same exact thing.